# Upload "Utterances" API not available in microsof CLU

Tags: dataset, botframework, azure-language-understanding, conversational-ai

I was using LUIS previously and using api, I would upload my json file containing intents, entities and utterances to my project. Now as LUIS is expired and Microsoft has replaced it with CLU(Conversational Language Understanding). I cannot find any API to upload my data(utterances) to CLU project.
I want to know what is alternative to this,
I want to automate the process of uploading my utterances to CLU.

I have gone through all the documentation of CLU authoring API but couldn't find any api to upload utterances.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option provided by Microsoft for migrating existing Luis into CLU in the LUIS account.

[image]

Click on the "Migrate to CLU" button and select the appropriate options given in the following screenshot.

**Prerequisite:** Create Langauge Service resource

[image]

**CLU API Documentation:**

- [CLU Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/language/2022-10-01-preview/conversational-analysis-authoring/import?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need a solution to upload my json/csv file containing the utterances to CLU programmatically,
do you mean, each time I want to upload a file, I will have to first upload to LUIS and then migrate LUIS to CLU?

Comment: First of all whenever you are doing each time upload then even LUIS also your LUIS app id will change and it is bad to practice. I don't see any programmatically upload API available in the CLU document. You can refer to my updated answer.